# find for a string in a column and replace with different text

Tags: excel, vba

I have a string like this. [A whole column of entries, the links are different]

"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodybuilding

Bodybuilding is a form of body modification, involving intensive muscle hypertrophy. An individual who engages in this activity is referred to as a bodybuilder. In competitive and professional bodybuilding, bodybuilders display their physiques to a panel of judges, who assign points based on their appearance. Bodybuilders prepare for competition through a combination of fat loss, oils, and tanning (or tanning lotions) which combined with lighting make the definition of the muscle group more distinct."

I need to search for any `"http://"` present inside the cell and replace only the

`"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodybuilding"`

with

`"<p><a title="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodybuilding " href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodybuilding " target="_self">http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodybuilding </a></p>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SEARCH/REPLACE wizard can do that for you.  Just press CTRL-H to open it and put in your FIND and REPLACE strings, set the ADVANCED OPTIONS to not match entire cells...

Here's a short macro version that does the same thing:

```
Sub Replace()

    Cells.Replace What:="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodybuilding", _
        Replacement:="<p><a title=""http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodybuilding"" href=""http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodybuilding"" target=""_self"">http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodybuilding </a></p>", _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```